# Wordpress: Requested Url not found

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm helping a friend getting her wordpress site online.

Sadly, all the site links are broken and i cannot log in to the wordpress backend(wp-admin) because she changed the url.

This is the url: http://projekts.dk/ <-- The Navigationbar is gone
but here is an example: http://projekts.dk/kontakt/

I have tried to search for an solution. But I simply couldn't find one. Maybe I'm missing something.

This is what i have tried so far.

- Search and replaced all links in the database with an Mysql Query
- Changed Perma_structure in wp_options from /%postname%/ to /%date%/ and back. To Try and change it manually.
- Deleted htaccess inserted it again.

What is left to try? Could glady use some help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had nearly the same problems and here is what I can suggest:

1. If your friend has migrated the server to another url or IP address, then go to the server and use the command `curl ifconfig.me`. With that you will have maybe the IP address. Run the commands below to change urls:

`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';`

`UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');`

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');`

`UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');`

Taken from [here](https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/) . I used this several times when I didn't have a static IP address.

2. The next thing you might wanna do is replace some WordPress files that may have been corrupted one way or another. Download a fresh WordPress folder from wordpress.org and replace the wp_login.php with the same file but from the downloaded folder. Helped me several times.

Comment: I have already done that. But i actually found out that i was looking in the wrong subfolder and found that htaccess was missing. So I've inserted it in to the wordpress site again. But all the pages look weird as fuck

Comment: I can now actually get to the login site. But all the fields are invisible and i cannot enter information into them

Comment: Well, if your pages are not rendering correctly, all looking like HTML from the 90s, then that means that your WordPress can't pull the themes and other front-end files. Maybe recheck your URLs/IP Addresses?